# Internet connection failed though Dial connection was successful using Ras library on Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows, ras

I am using DotRas library, creating RasDevice, Rasentry , adding Rasentry to RasPhoneBook and finally calling RasDialer.Dial().

```
RasDevice device = RasDevice.GetDevices().Where(o => o.Name == "(PPPOE)" && o.DeviceType == RasDeviceType.PPPoE).FirstOrDefault();
            if (device != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Found " + device.Name.ToString() + device.DeviceType.ToString(), "hah!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Device not found", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }

           RasEntry entry = RasEntry.CreateDialUpEntry("Dialupnamexyz", "+880000000", device);
            this.rasPhoneBook1.Entries.Add(entry);


       this.rasDialer1.EntryName = EntryNameSet;
            this.rasDialer1.PhoneBookPath = RasPhoneBook.GetPhoneBookPath(RasPhoneBookType.AllUsers); ;
            this.rasDialer1.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, userPassword);
            this.rasDialer1.DialAsync();
```

Connection is established. However, when i tried using internet explorer its down.

I tried manually dialing up the programmatically created entry, it say connection established. But again in internet explorer its down.

I am using windows 10. Is there anything i am missing here? 
Thanks for help.